# Linked-in displays correct thumbnail for one WordPress post but not the other

Tags: html, wordpress, image, linkedin-api

I have two articles on my WordPress site, which uses Yost SEO to provide the appropriate open graph metatags for the Linked-In crawler to grab the needed feature image. On previous posts, it works just fine but on the latest one that was posted, it grabs an image further down the page rather than the feature image specified by the og:image property. Here are the links to the two posts in question:

This one works as expected:
https://www.midstory.org/how-climate-change-is-shaping-michigans-coastal-management/

This one displays the incorrect thumbnail:
https://www.midstory.org/cow-culture-and-the-elsie-dairy-festival/

I tried comparing the meta tags between the two pages and I don't see any meaningful diferences between then two:

Working page:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="https://www.midstory.org/wp-content/uploads/2022/06/cover-2.jpeg">
<meta property="og:image:width" content="1200">
<meta property="og:image:height" content="628">
<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpeg">
```

Non-working page:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="https://www.midstory.org/wp-content/uploads/2022/06/Cow-Festival-Graphic_3-w-spray-paint.jpg">
<meta property="og:image:width" content="1200">
<meta property="og:image:height" content="628">
<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpeg">
```

I did use the Linked-In post inspector to refresh the cached image for the second post, but it still keeps grabbing the wrong image. What else am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that Linked-In still doesn't support webp formatted images. I saved the image as a normal .jpg and it worked after re-uploading it.

Comment: it appears you are answering your own question with another user profile..?

Comment: I was wondering why I couldn't mark it as an answer!?.... Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: why don't you use your original profile (from the question)? feels a bit shady ;-)